# Jest with Babel-jest not compiling js in parent folders

Tags: javascript, jestjs, babel-jest

I have a problem when i run jest from a folder and some file are in a parent directory.

My repository seems like that :

```
|-common
|  |-.babelrc
|  |-src
|    |-js
|      |-someDependencies.js
|-app
   |-src
   | |-js
   |   |-someCodeIncludingSomeDependencies.js
   |-.babelrc
   |-package.json 
   |-webpack.config.js
```

My Jest configuration is in package.json and is :

```
    "jest": {
        "moduleNameMapper": {
            "^vue$": "vue/dist/vue.common.js",
            "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1",
            "^@Common/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/../common/src/$1"
        },
        "moduleFileExtensions": [
            "js",
            "vue"
        ],
        "snapshotSerializers": [
            "jest-serializer-vue"
        ],
        "transform": {
            "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
            ".+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$": "jest-transform-stub",
            ".*\\.(vue)$": "vue-jest"
        },
        "collectCoverageFrom": [
            "**/*.{js,vue}",
            "!**/dist/**",
            "!<rootDir>/coverage/**",
            "!**/node_modules/**"
        ],
        "transformIgnorePatterns": [
            "<rootDir>/node_modules/"
        ]
    },
```

I run Jest from 'app' folder.

My problem is when I run Jest the code in 'common/src/js' is not transformed by babel and make error :

```
...
SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

      3 | 
      4 | 
    > 5 | export default {}
        | ^
...
```

Answer (score 0):

> New in Babel 7.x, Babel has as concept of a "root" directory, which defaults to the current working directory.

For more info you can read [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files).

Just specify the `root` property in your `.babelrc` file to point to the parent folder or you can move the `.babelrc` file to that parent.

Answer (score 0):

I solve issue in changing '.babelrc' config file into a 'babel.config.js' file...